# Convert Textbox Text to Date while text changing

Tags: c#

What I want is when user input text in textbox in normal way, text change to date format.
for example when user are entering 20110110 text change to 2011/01/10

Comment: You mean you want to format the text the user enters?  `TextBox.Text` is a string.

Comment: What UI framework are you using? If it's WinForms there's a MaskedTextBox which might help.

Answer (score 2):

At what point would you do that? The instant they typed the final "0"?

You *could* hook into the [`TextChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged.aspx) event and do something like:

```
public void ReformatDate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = (TextBox) sender;

    DateTime dt;
    // TODO: Work out what culture you want to parse/format in.
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(textBox.Text, "yyyyMMdd",
                               DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
    {
        textBox.Text = dt.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
    }
}
```

Personally I'm not sure that as a user I'd *want* that behaviour, mind you. You might want to do this when the text box loses focus instead.

Comment: It was similar to what I want. But not exactly. anyway I've got an idea from your code and I will change it.. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user422481: What does that not do that you wanted it to? Perhaps you should update your question.